# Prove $|AC_1|/|BC_1|=\sin(2\beta)/\sin(2\alpha)$.

Tags: geometry

Let $O$ be the center of the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$ and $C_1$ be the intersection of $CO$ and $AB$. Prove $|AC_1|/|BC_1|=\sin(2\beta)/\sin(2\alpha)$.

I don't know how to prove this statement... I've tried using sine theorems in many triangles but it doesn't work out.

Comment: I request an illustrative diagram.  Please see the **Edit-Images** section in [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta?$ The opposite angles of $A$ and $B,$ respectively?

Comment: Yes, they are the opposite angles.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{AC_1}{BC_1} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}.AC_1.h_c}{\frac{1}{2}.BC_1.h_c} = \frac{S_{ACC_1}}{S_{BCC_1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}.AC.CC_1.\sin\angle ACC_1}{\frac{1}{2}.BC.CC_1.\sin\angle BCC_1} &= \frac{AC}{BC}.\frac{\sin \angle ACC_1}{\sin\angle BCC_1}\\
\color{gray}{\small{\text{(Law of sines & $\angle ACC_1 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \beta$ & $\angle BCC_1 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$)}}} &= \frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}.\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \beta)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha)}\\
&= \frac{\sin\beta.\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha.\cos\alpha}\\
&= \frac{\sin 2\beta}{\sin 2\alpha}\\
\end{align*}